# Creating a singleton bean using runtime parameters

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am new to the Spring framework and can't find a way to achieve the following:

I am using a class whose attributes are all private and there are no setters (the intended way to use objects of that class is to set attributes once with a constructor) - I will refer to it as *Preferences*. I also have a few classes that each has the same instance of *Preferences* as an attribute. *Preferences* is intended to contain certain properties, among which some can only be resolved at runtime (e.g. provided by the user).

In my .xml file I would write something along the lines of:

```
<bean id="preferenes" class="Preferences" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="defaultAttrOne" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="defaultAttrTwo" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="defaultAttrThree" />
</bean>

<bean id="someOtherBean" class="SomeOtherClass" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="preferences" />
</bean>
```

That is, I could provide default values and replace some of them with custom ones at runtime. As I cannot modify attributes of an existing instance of *Preferences*, I would have to construct a new object and somehow make the instance of SomeOtherClass point to that new object (is this possible through the bean mechanism?).

Rather, I'd pass the desired runtime constructor arguments to the *preferences* bean before instantiating any of the beans (those arguments will be known before the first call to the ApplicationContext's constructor). I know there is a flavour of the getBean() method that takes varargs as initialization parameters, though it only applies to prototype beans. In this case I want to initialize *Preferenes* once and have all helper classes refer to that single instance.

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Use property resolution.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: Use property placeholders `${somePropertyName}` and configure a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Then add the properties at runtime before you refresh the `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what Spring does for you by default so there is nothing special you'll have to do: if you create that singleton bean reference (called `preferences`), you'll be able to inject it to any other bean as you would expect.

Regarding your attributes with default values, there's several ways to achieve that:

### Regular XML config

You can keep a purely XML-based configuration if you want and configure a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with default values. Something like:

```
<bean class="org.s.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">      
    <property name="location" value="prefrences.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="preferenes" class="Preferences" scope="singleton">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="$[preferences.one:12]" />
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="$[preferences.two:AUTO]" />
   <constructor-arg index="2" value="$[preferences.three:false]" />
</bean>
```

And have a `prefrences.properties` at the root of the classpath hold the specific values if you don't want the default

```
prefrences.three=true
```

### FactoryBean

As you're already using XML, you can go with a [`FactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) that would create the `Preferences` instance, something like

```
<bean id="preferences" class="org.myproject.PreferencesFactoryBean"/>
```

in the code of the factory you could use whatever mechanism you want to retrieve the non default values for your configuration, including injecting custom properties.

### Java config

You can also go the java config way but as you're a beginner this may be a bit of a change. However, java config is really powerful and flexible so you may want to give it a try.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:preferences.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${preferences.one}")
    private int preferenceOne = 12;

    @Value("${preferences.two}")
    private MyEnum preferenceTwo = MyEnum.AUTO;

    @Value("${preferences.three}")
    private boolean preferenceThree;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Preferences preferences() {
        return new Preferences(preferenceOne, preferenceTwo, preferenceThree);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, though it's still not quite what I aim to achieve. The arguments I'd like to pass to the Preferences bean don't reside in a properties file (maybe I misused the word 'properties' in my question). Instead, they are to be provided at the code level and can be instances of some custom classes. Sticking to the annotation convention, I'd have a @Value("${myClass}")-annotated MyClass myClass field used by the preferences bean (like in your example above). From outside the config class I'd like to set the myClass field first and then call getBean(Preferences.class).

Comment: You can't do that. It's like if you wanted to manage an object state and then after ask Spring to take care of it. This is the reason why such thing used to be provided by declarative means such as properties file because the container manages it. That being said, there's nothing wrong with anything that I have provided to you above. You can create a FactoryBean and have all the logic you want in getObject. For Java config (third example) you can call whatever you need in preferences() and remove the @Value fields